# Python 3.2 File I/O. Generating & Spliting a file based on preset size limit. How?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on some code that generates all permutations of a given set of characters. Although my code works in Python 2.7 it no longer does in Python 3.x due to many changes in Strings. I'd like to adapt and since I'm new to Python, I was hoping you could give me a little push. =)

**My question is**, as Python generates the word list of your choice, the output file size grows accordingly. I'd like you to show me how can I make this script check for a preset file size and if reached, open a new file and continue writing permutations.

Example:

numeric_lowercase.000001
numeric_lowercase.000002
numeric_lowercase.000003

**Remember**, I have looked at most examples on the site but they do not work with Python 3.2.

Here's my Python 3.2 working code so far:

```
import itertools
import subprocess
import os
from string import digits, ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, punctuation

if os.name == 'nt':
    def clear_console():
        subprocess.call("cls", shell=True)
        return
else:
    def clear_console():
        subprocess.call("clear", shell=True)
        return

def generate_phone_numbers(area_code):
    f = open('phones.txt', 'w')
    for i in range(2010000, 9999999):
        f.write(area_code + str(i) + '\n')

def generate_wordlist(lst_chars, min_digit, max_digit, lst_name):
    f = open(lst_name, 'w')
    for curr_length in range(min_digit, max_digit + 1):
        for curr_digit in itertools.product(lst_chars, repeat=curr_length):
            f.write(''.join(curr_digit) + '\n')

print ('')
print ('  wgen - Menu')

choice = 0

while int(choice) not in range(1,6):
    clear_console()
    choice = input('''
  1. Phone numbers for a given area code.
  2. Numbers.
  3. Numbers + Lowercase.
  4. Numbers + Lowercase + Uppercase.
  5. Numbers + Lowercase + Uppercase + Punctuation.

  Enter Option: ''')

print ('')

choice = int(choice)

if choice == 1:
    area_code = input('''
  Please enter Area Code: ''')
    area_code = str(area_code)
    area_code = area_code.strip()
    if len(area_code) == 3:
        print ('')
        print ('  Generating phone numbers for area code ' + area_code + '.')
        print ('  Please wait...')
        generate_phone_numbers(area_code)

if choice == 2:
    min_digit = input('  What is the minimum size of the word? ')
    min_digit = int(min_digit)
    print ('')
    max_digit = input('  What is the maximum size of the word? ')
    max_digit = int(max_digit)
    chars = digits
    lst_name = 'numeric.txt'
    print ('')
    print ('  Generating numbers between ' + str(min_digit) + ' and ' + str(max_digit) + ' digits.')
    print ('  Please wait...')
    generate_wordlist(chars, min_digit, max_digit, lst_name)

if choice == 3:
    min_digit = input('  What is the minimum size of the word? ')
    min_digit = int(min_digit)
    print ('')
    max_digit = input('  What is the maximum size of the word? ')
    max_digit = int(max_digit)
    chars = digits + ascii_lowercase
    lst_name = 'numeric_lowercase.txt'
    print ('')
    print ('  Generating numbers & lowercase between ' + str(min_digit) + ' and ' + str(max_digit) + ' digits.')
    print ('  Please wait...')
    generate_wordlist(chars, min_digit, max_digit, lst_name)

if choice == 4:
    min_digit = input('  What is the minimum size of the word? ')
    min_digit = int(min_digit)
    print ('')
    max_digit = input('  What is the maximum size of the word? ')
    max_digit = int(max_digit)
    chars = digits + ascii_lowercase + ascii_uppercase
    lst_name = 'numeric_lowercase_uppercase.txt'
    print ('')
    print ('  Generating numbers, lowercase & uppercase between ' + str(min_digit) + ' and ' + str(max_digit) + ' digits.')
    print ('  Please wait...')
    generate_wordlist(chars, min_digit, max_digit, lst_name)

if choice == 5:
    min_digit = input('  What is the minimum size of the word? ')
    min_digit = int(min_digit)
    print ('')
    max_digit = input('  What is the maximum size of the word? ')
    max_digit = int(max_digit)
    chars = punctuation
    lst_name = 'numeric_lowercase_uppercase_punctuation.txt'
    print ('')
    print ('  Generating numbers, lowercase, uppercase & punctuation between ' + str(min_digit) + ' and ' + str(max_digit) + ' digits.')
    print ('  Please wait...')
    generate_wordlist(chars, min_digit, max_digit, lst_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution would be to write a class that acts like a file, but provides the chunking capability. Your program just writes to this object as though it were a regular file.

The implementation below won't split strings (if you call `f.write("this is a test")` the entire message is guaranteed to go in one file) and it only starts a new one when the limit is exceeded, so files will be somewhat larger than the chunk size. This behavior is all in the `write()` method and could be changed if desired.

```
class chunkyfile(object):
    def __init__(self, filename, chunksize=1000000, mode="w", encoding=None, 
                 extension="", start=0, digits=6):
        self.filename  = filename
        self.chunksize = chunksize
        self.chunkno   = start
        self.file      = None
        self.mode      = mode
        self.encoding  = encoding
        self.digits    = digits
        self.extension = ("." * bool(extension) * (not extension.startswith(".")) +
                          extension)
        self.softspace = 0       # for use with print

    def _nextfile(self):
        self.file and self.file.close()
        self.file = open(self.filename + str(self.chunkno).rjust(self.digits, "0") + 
                         self.extension, mode=self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
        self.chunkno += 1

    def write(self, text):
        self.file and self.file.tell() > self.chunksize and self.close()
        self.file or self._nextfile()
        self.file.write(text)

    # convenience method, equivalent to print(... file=f)
    # requires Python 3.x or from __future__ import print in Py2
    def print(*objects, sep=" ", end="\n", flush=False):
        print(*objects, sep=sep, end=end, flush=flush, file=self)

    def writelines(self, lines):
        # do it a line at a time in case we need to split
        for line in lines: self.write(line)

    def flush(self):
        self.file and self.file.flush()

    def close(self):
        self.file = self.file and self.file.close()

    # support "with" statement
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, e, value, tb):
        self.close()

# now use the file
with chunkyfile(r"C:\test", 10, extension="txt", encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.write("FINALLY ROBOTIC BEINGS RULE THE WORLD")
    f.write("The humans are dead")
    f.write("The humans are dead")
    f.write("We used poisonous gasses")
    f.write("And we poisoned their asses")
```

Comment: Thanks kindall. I just noticed that although your code works, it does not create new files. Once it is done filling up one file, it simply erases this or the contents of this file and writes new stuff to it.

Comment: Works fine in my test. I added more to the example, with a chunk size of ten bytes.  This results in each `write()` going to a new file since it's longer than ten bytes.

Comment: I deleted the code you added to my answer, but at first glance I didn't see anything in it that wouldn't work in Python 3. What problem are you seeing? Maybe add it to your question?

Comment: in my old code you deleted, i got errors:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\New Folder\new.py", line 67, in <module>
    out.write(''.join(tmp) + '\r' + '\n')
  File "D:\New Folder\new.py", line 29, in write
    self._output.write(data)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: Ah, that's because you're writing the file as binary (mode `"wb"`) but are providing a string, which in Python is not a binary object but a Unicode object with more than one binary representation. Just wrap the value in `bytes()` and optionally tell Python what encoding to use (such as `utf-8`). Or open the file in text mode instead of binary.

Comment: Working fine in python 3.2, and very logical.  Mind you, I'm not against the logging solution, code reuse is good and all, I just like how this plugs in neatly and isn't going to make a new reader of the code do a double-take when they realize what all that logging stuff is really about.

Comment: right on guys. Thanks a lot. Hey. I just had one last question. When you are writing lines to a file in binary, what is the binary representation of '\n' or '\r\n'? Or Does it even matter?

Comment: What to use for newline would depend on what encoding the file's using. For UTF-8, you can use almost anything and it'll be valid. For ASCII it depends on what platform you or on (or want to be able to read your files), though in practice most programs on most platforms (except Notepad.exe on Windows) can handle CR, LF, or CR+LF.

Comment: By the way, the reason for binary is to get a precise file size versus writing to file in text mode.

Comment: I worked around that by asking the file how many bytes are in it, rather than trying to count them.

Comment: I had one quick question. Do you think it is possible to add some sort of Pause and Resume functionality to it? It's a bit over my head if so.

Comment: Assuming it's a command-line program, the easiest way would be to send the output to the terminal as well as to the file(s), so the user could pause and resume using the usual terminal controls. It wouldn't have to be the entire data, it could easily be just a dot every time a line gets written. You could add something like that to the `write()` method if you wanted. For a GUI app, you would have to do it very differently.

Comment: Seven years later, fixed a bug, shortened the code up a bit, and added support for passing a mode, so you could write binary if you want.

Answer (score 2):

With a little bit of up front configuration you can use the RotatingFileHandler built into the logging library in stdlib.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

log = logging.getLogger('myprog.stufflogger')
log.propagate = False #ensure that we don't mess with other logging

#configure RotatingFileHandler
handler = RotatingFileHandler('base_file_name.txt', maxBytes=1024*1024*20)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
handler.terminator = '' # default is new line

log.addHandler(handler)


# you can now use any of the log methods to add the values

log.info('stuff')
```